# can i mark the dog with this model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I saw this code on the youtube [How to use your trained model - Deep Learning basics with Python, TensorFlow and Keras p.6](https://youtu.be/A4K6D_gx2Iw)

If I bring a picture, he tells me if the picture is cat or dog.

I can use this code and mark the dog/cat in the picture?

Or do I need to run a brand-new model?

in the code I get all pic of dog and cat and put it in X  and y

X = it's the features

y = it the label

**the code**

```
dense_layers = [0]
layer_sizes = [64]
conv_layers = [3]



model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3, 3), input_shape=X.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(layer_size, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(layer_size))
 model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
               optimizer='adam',
               metrics=['accuracy'],
                )

model.fit(X, y,
          batch_size=32,
          epochs=10,
          validation_split=0.3,
          )

model.save('64x3-CNN.model')
```

after he save it he can use it on some picture and get the write answer

I want to add to it the possibility of marking the dog or cat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Questions are not clear but, Let me answer one by one.

**1)** *Q: can I use this code and mark the dog/cat in the picture?*

> *A: Yes you can. However, you should have the saved model to use it. Otherwise you have to train the model and save it again.*

**2)** *Q: I want to add to it the possibility of marking the dog or cat. Is this possible?*

> *A: Yes, it is possible. `model.predict` would yield you the probabilities.

Comment: This code lets me find the picture with the dog,
I'm looking to mark the dog with a square.


How can I mark the dog with a square in the selected picture?

Comment: Well it's a different task called **localization**. Since this model is only for **classification** task, it is not possible to localize the object and draw a bounding box for it. You should take a look for the localization in keras I believe.

Comment: So I have to retrain him again?
Can you guide me in which way I should train now? 
Thank you

Comment: Not only retrain, you should add a new model for localization also. It's a pretty long and complicated topic to guide it about but you can start with searching in Google that _Keras object localization guide_